# How can I aggregate filtered nested documents in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose I have an index with nested document that looks like this:

```
{
    "id" : 1234
    "cars" : [{
            "id" : 987
            "name" : "Volkswagen"
        }, {
            "id": 988
            "name" : "Tesla"
        }
    ]
}
```

I now want to get a count aggregation of "car" documents that match a certain criteria, e.g. that match a search query. My initial attempt was the following query:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "nested" : {
      "path" : "cars",
      "query" : {
        "query_string" : {
          "fields" : ["cars.name"],
          "query" : "Tes*"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "cars" :{
      "nested" : {
        "path" : "cars"
      },
      "aggs" : {
        "cars" : {
          "terms" : {
            "field" : "cars.id"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I was hoping here to get an aggregation result with only the ids of cars whose name begin with "Tes". However, the aggregation instead uses all cars that are in a top-level document that also contains a matching nested documents. That is, in the above example "Volkswagen" would also be counted because the top-level document also contains a car that does match.

How can I get an aggregation of just the matching nested documents?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the mean time I've figured it out: to achieve this a filter aggregation should be added around the the terms aggregation like so:

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "cars" :{
      "nested" : {
        "path" : "cars"
      },
      "aggs" : {
        "cars-filter" : {
          "filter" : {
            "query" : {
              "query_string" : {
                "fields" : ["cars.name"],
                "query" : "Tes*"
              }
            }  
          },
          "aggs" : {
            "cars" : {
              "terms" : {
                "field" : "cars.id"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure this code works? I'm facing the same issue, but when I try your code I get a `parsing_exception` "no [query] registered for [query]"

Comment: It definitely did work when I created this query, but the query format of ES hasn't always stayed backwards compatible . IIRC I wrote this query for ES1.x, newer versions might not accept it.

Comment: Yes, @Tiddo - I get the same response as you. Can't see how to do this for the current version. Let me know if you got anywhere with it.

Comment: There is no "filter" query anymore.  You need to use a bool query with a filter clause instead.

Comment: @Tiddo Can you provide above query in 5.6.7 ES format?